# SQL sum values from different tables using item_details group by order_id and order_date

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregate-functions, calculated-columns

I have multiple tables. I only wanted to operate on these two. The objective is to project the order_id, sum of (total order cost calculated from multiple table), order_date ---grouped by each one order_id and sorted by order_date.

It sounds quite simple, but I have multiple queries, sum gave error & wrong result. I m far from getting the correct simple query for this.

Here are the tables and data :

Order_Table :

```
ORDERID CUSTOMERID EMPLOYEEID ORDERDATE PURCHASEORDERNUMBER SHIPDATE  SHIPPINGMETHODID FREIGHTCHARGE TAXES PAYMENTRECEIVED COMMENTS
------- ---------- ---------- --------- ------------------- --------- ---------------- ------------- ----- --------------- -------------------
      1          2        1   23-JAN-05     10                29-JAN-05              1            64     5    0
      2          1        1   23-JAN-05     11                29-JAN-05              1             0     5    0
      3          3        3   21-JAN-05     30                28-JAN-05              5             0     5    0
      4          2        2   05-JAN-05     26                19-JAN-05              2             0     5    0
      5          4        5   02-JAN-05     32                27-JAN-05              2             0     5    0
     13          1        1   29-JAN-08      1                                       2            50     5    0
```

6 rows selected

Order_Detail_Table :

ORDERDETAILID ORDERID PRODUCTID QUANTITY UNITPRICE DISCOUNT

---

```
        1       1         4       15         5        0 
        2       2         7       10        75        0 
        3       3         8        5         4        0 
        5       4         9      100         5     0.05 
        6       5         6        5         7        0 
        7       5         9       30         5     0.05 
        9       1         1        9         6        0 
       11      13         4        1         5        0 
       12      13         1        2        25        0 
       13      13         7        1        75        0
```

10 rows selected

So for example for orderid = 13. We have 3 items ordered listed on the order_detail_table.
For the unique orderid=13, I want to calculate 3 rows of (quantity*unitprice)*(1-discount). It will be 130 for orderid=13

```
select o.orderid, sum((od.unitprice*od.quantity)*(1-od.discount*0.01)) as total from order_table o, order_detail_table od
where o.orderid=od.orderid group by o.orderid;
```

Then using those values, I would like to add the final summed values with the individual freightcharge + taxes. = (130+50)*(1+tax%) = 180*(1.05) = 189 for the row orderid=13.
I am stuck here, to add with the order_table.freight etc. I just met with compile and logic errors.

```
select o.orderid, (sum((od.unitprice*od.quantity)*(1-od.discount*0.01)) + o.freightcharge) as total from order_table o, order_detail_table od
where o.orderid=od.orderid group by o.orderid;
```

Gives me SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression --- Idk why as I think the sum is only aggregate function to be grouped, while + o.freightcharge is outside of sum.

```
select o.orderid, sum((od.unitprice*od.quantity)*(1-od.discount*0.01)) + sum(o.freightcharge) as total from order_table o, order_detail_table od
where o.orderid=od.orderid group by o.orderid;
```

Gives me 3 x freightcharges, for single order in case of orderid=13. --Wrong logic.

There should be 6 rows for each unique orderid.
I tried building from several simpler queries. But I havent got success. As I think I might need to use subqueries

Pls Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you combine the freightcharge from order_detail_table with aggregated data. Something like that should solve the problem:

```
select o.orderid, sq.total+o.freightcharge
from order_table o
left join
(
  select o.orderid, sum((od.unitprice*od.quantity)*(1-od.discount*0.01)) as total 
  from order_table o, order_detail_table od
  where o.orderid=od.orderid group by o.orderid
) sq
on sq.orderid=o.order_id;
```

Comment: select o.orderid, (sq.total+o.freightcharge)*(1+o.taxes*0.01), o.shipdate
from order_table o
left join
(
  select o.orderid, sum((od.unitprice*od.quantity)*(1-od.discount*0.01)) as total 
  from order_table o, order_detail_table od
  where o.orderid=od.orderid group by o.orderid
) sq
on sq.orderid=o.orderid order by o.shipdate;

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you:

```
;with OrderTotals
AS
(
select 
    o.orderid
    ,o.freightcharge
    ,sum((od.unitprice*od.quantity)*(1-od.discount*0.01)) as total 
from 
    order_table o
 inner join
    order_detail_table od
 on o.orderid = od.orderid 
 group by 
    o.orderid
    ,o.freightcharge
)
 select
    OrderTotals.OrderId                 AS OrderId
    ,OrderTotals.Total                  AS OrderTotal
    ,OrderTotals.Total + freightcharge  AS Total
from
    OrderTotals
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.orderid,((od.total + o.FREIGHTCHARGE) * (1 + o.TAXES * 0.01)) AS result 
 FROM order_table o JOIN 
    (
     SELECT orderid, sum((unitprice*quantity)*(1-discount*0.01)) AS total FROM    
        order_detail_table GROUP BY orderid
    ) as od ON o.orderid=od.orderid
```